# Matlab does not recognise my function

Tags: functions, matlab, programming

After running the code

```
xone = 2.5;
xtwo = 3.5;
root = bisection(xone,xtwo);

function root = bisection(xone,xtwo)
    while abs(funcx(xthree)) > 0.0001
        xthree = (xone+xtwo)/2;
        if funcx(xthree) > 0
            xone = xthree;
        elseif funcx(xthree) < 0
            xtwo = xthree;
        else
    end
    root = xthree;
end

function fofx = funcx(x)
    fofx = 3 * exp(-x) - x + 3;
end

disp(root)
```

I get the error

> Unrecognized function or variable 'bisection'.

As far as I am aware, I have nested my function correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Typesetting this in TeX/MathJax would vastly improve its readability, and would get more people to take the trouble to read it.

Comment: There are multiple issues with the code.  Do you have it open in MATLAB's editor?  If so, it will highlight obvious errors.  I suggest doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You code has 3 errors. The main error is that you shouldn't put the line of "disp(root);" after any definition of your functions. This can be fixed by moving it to the line before the line of "function root = bisection(...)".

The second error is that in the definition of "function root = bisection(...)", the variable 'xthree' is not defined in the line of "while abs(funcx(xthree))...". This can be fixed by adding "xthree = 1;" before the line of "while abs(funcx(xthree))...".

The third error is that the ending statement of the "if" loop in the definition of "function root = bisection(...)" should be "end", not "else".